# Switch from Main dispatcher to IO dispatcher from non lifecycle class

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I m using coroutines in my android app, and i have this function that need to communicate with UI and Main thread.

```
private suspend fun init() : RequestProcessor<LocalData, ApiResult, ApiError>
{
    @Suppress("LeakingThis")
    _localData = listener.databaseCall()
    
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        
        if (_localData == null)
        {
            checkIfShouldFetch(null, null)
        }
        else
        {
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                
                mediatorLiveData.addSource(_localData!!) { newLocalData ->
                    mediatorLiveData.removeSource(_localData!!)
                    
                    // I want to call this from the IO thread.
                    checkIfShouldFetch(newLocalData, _localData)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    return this
}
```

My question is, how to come back to the root context (**IO**) from the nested context (**Main**)?

when i call again **withContext(Dispatchers.IO)** this error is displayed : **Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body**

I need to call the function **checkIfShouldFetch(newLocalData, _localData)** from the **IO** context and i didn't find how to do it.

Comment: Your problem isn't nesting `withContext`, but trying to call a suspending function from within the body of a regular, non-suspending callback. One of the answers below covers how to convert an async call with a callback to a sync suspendable call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to launch a coroutine to call `withContext` in that place. What you can try to do without launching a coroutine is to use `suspendCoroutine` or `suspendCancellableCoroutine` to suspend execution until callback is fired:

```
withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
    val newLocalData = addSource()
    checkIfShouldFetch(newLocalData, _localData)
}

suspend fun addSource(): LiveData<...> = suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
    mediatorLiveData.addSource(_localData) { newLocalData ->
        mediatorLiveData.removeSource(_localData)

        continuation.resumeWith(newLocalData)
    }
}

suspend fun checkIfShouldFetch(newLocalData: ..., _localData: ...) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: ```suspendCoroutine```  would block ```MainThread``` in this context. Despite on it is not an issue in case of ```addSource()``` function call, it might be the issue in case of heavy operations like in my use case. Do you know any other alternative for switching ```Dispatchers``` thread in similar context?

Comment: To switch Dispatchers for heavy computation `withContext(Dispatchers.Default)` or `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` can be used.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up with this solution. I was not sure it a safe to switch ```Dispatchers``` within each other.